# What is the source of wealth of the Potter family?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards

Harry Potter was born into a wealthy family. He inherited lots of gold from his father. What did his father do to get so rich?

I have always been puzzled about how the wizards get rich. The Muggle economy is much larger and has more opportunities to become rich. What can wizards do to become rich? They cannot sell magical products/services to the Muggles. The wizard population is much smaller, so making money from this smaller market is much harder.